# How embed code snippet into conversation?

Tags: github

I can't figure out how embed code snippets into my conversation, like this:

[image: Embedded code snippet example]

From google I found some tutorials like:
[Introducing Embedded Code Snippets](https://github.blog/2017-08-15-introducing-embedded-code-snippets/) / [Embedded Code Snippets](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet) / [Creating a Permanent Link to a Code Snippet](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet) (they are all github official help documents)

and I tried follow them, but instead of showing nice box it shows as:
[image]

Did I miss something - maybe I have to enable it somewhere or is it available only for github Pro and Staff versions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer:

Permanent link will render as a code snippet only in the repository it **originated in**.

In other repositories, the permalink code snippet will render as a **URL**.

Comment: Where did you find this answer. I'm experiencing the same behavior but no where in the docs states this.

Comment: Found it https://github.com/github/docs/blob/fda5e0fa846c2ae60845c04a6687c7eb41ecdaf5/content/get-started/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet.md?plain=1#L20