# GitHub code permalink does not paste lines

Tags: github, github-issues

I am trying to comment the following lines in a GitHub issue:

https://github.com/AMP-SCZ/dpanonymize/blob/49282b5c67ca1f88e7a651bc724e639b97e819d9/dpanonymize/__init__.py#L63-L69

However, after I paste it in the comment box, it does not show the lines like the following does:

https://github.com/pnlbwh/luigi-pnlpipe/blob/87603cf59eaa09dc64bed447496841bfcb11e3e8/workflows/_glob.py#L4-L14

Does anyone know the problem with the former?

Comment: I realize that permalink translates to actual code only within the repository of the permalink. Is it expected?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to web applications

Comment: I am not sure how and what web applications and GitHub mingle but thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How embed code snippet into conversation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66723776/how-embed-code-snippet-into-conversation)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to:

https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/working-with-advanced-formatting/creating-a-permanent-link-to-a-code-snippet#linking-to-code

> This type of permanent link will render as a code snippet only in the repository it originated in. In other repositories, the permalink code snippet will render as a URL.

Comment: I had the same Q. Actually reading-the-docs is not our forte haha.